# Node form alter place default value for select list

Tags: hooks, forms

I have node form for Images content type which have a `taxonomy term reference` field. It is a `select` field with the options in it. Now I am trying to place a default value for the field by checking the `tid` which is coming from the URL using `$_GET` and `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter`

My code is

```
$term = isset($_GET['term_id']) ? $_GET['term_id'] : '';
$form['field_term'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#default_value'][] = trim($term_id);
```

When I print the form it gives me this:

```
[#default_value] => Array
 (
   [0] => 9913
 )
```

But it is not showing up on the form.

When I try to set the default value from the content type field settings UI it shows up and also the array structure is same. But even though via from alter the structure is same it doesn't show in the node form.

FYI have also tried out the following options:

```
$form['field_term'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#default_value'] = trim($term_id);

$form['field_term'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#default_value'] = $term_id;

$form['field_term'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#default_value'] = $term_id;

$form['field_term'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#value'] = $term_id;

$form['field_term'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['value'] = $term_id;
```

Comment: Try `$form['field_term'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['tid']['#default_value'] = ...` or `$form['field_term'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid']['#default_value'] = ...` (can't remember which one's right off the top of my head)

Comment: Tried it out. No luck.

Comment: For me simply `$form['field_term'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#default_value'] = $term_id;` working fine. Issue seems that term id you are passing is not in the select list.

Comment: Is it a single or multiple cardinality field? You would only pass an array if it's multiple

Comment: Sorry guys. Big silly mistake from my end. The form alter parameters were not correct.
Gave `$form, &$form_state, &$form_id` instead of `&$form, &$form_state, $form_id`
Its working now.

Comment: since it was just a typo, be sure to close the question once you can as it cannot help anyone in the future

Comment: @MalabyaTewari, you can [answer your own question](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). You should leave an answer about how your solved the problem.